# How to use where/whereDate in mongodb aggregate functions using Jessengers package in Laravel?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query

How to use where/whereDate in aggregate mongodb query ?

I am using aggregate query in laravel and [jessenger-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) to group by fields.

The problem here is, I need to add a condition to fetch grouped data of a particular date i.e `created_at`.

Following code worked perfectly if I do not use pass `$date` i.e `$date = null`:

```
public static function getUsersByTypeLogin($date = null)
    {

        $q = self::raw()->aggregate(
            [
                array(
                    '$match' => array(
                        'type' => self::LOGIN,
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    '$group' => array(
                        '_id' => array(
                            'lat' => '$latitude',
                            'long' => '$longitude',
                            'country' => '$country',
                            'state' => '$state'
                        ),
                        'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
                    )
                )
            ]
        );

        if(true == $date){
            $q = $q->whereDate('created_at','=',$date);
        }

        return $q;
    }
```

but If I pass `$date` it returns an error, it says:

`message: "Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::whereDate()"`

$date is a Carbon object e.g:

```
Carbon @1549843200 {#791
  date: 2019-02-11 00:00:00.0 +00:00
}
```

Please help me in this regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$q = self::raw(function($collection) use($date) {
    return $collection->aggregate([
        array(
            '$match' => array(
                'type' => self::LOGIN,
                'created_date' => $date,
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => array(
                    'lat' => '$latitude',
                    'long' => '$longitude',
                    'country' => '$country',
                    'state' => '$state'
                ),
                'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
            )
        )
    ]);
});
```

Comment: @DineshSuthar Updated my answer can you try that and let me know if any error come

Comment: what if `$date` passed is null ? I want to use conditions eg. If date is passed then match with `created_at` otherwise do not.

Comment: @DineshSuthar this solution is working for you if the date is passed?

Comment: No, I am getting empty array: 
1) Carbon date object: Carbon @1549843200 {#791
  date: 2019-02-11 00:00:00.0 +00:00
}

2) Resultant array: []

Comment: remove created_at condition and show collection->aggregate dump result I want to check what they are returning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188205/discussion-between-jigar-halani-and-dinesh-suthar).

Comment: See this [paste-bin](https://pastebin.com/L6vyjMaX), it contains the json document and my laravel function